# stop an IIFE from execution if a condition occurs

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm trying to build an application that plans for the user's week, everything is going Ok except one thing when the user inputs a duplicated time an error shows up but my problem is the application is still running the plan shows up in the UI.

so I tried to use the `return` keyword to prevent the app from continue working but that didn't do the trick so here is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
var internalController = (function(UICtrl) { 
  var Plan = function(id, from, to, text, goingToCkecked) {
    this.id = id;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.text = text;
    this.goingToCkecked = goingToCkecked;
  };

  var data = {
    Monday: [],
    Tuesday: [],
    Wednesday: [],
    Thursday: [],
    Friday: [],
    Saturday: [],
    Sunday: []
  };

  //the array of the from inputs
  var fromT = [];

  //the array of the to inputs
  var toT = [];

  var Dom = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

  function removeError(x, y) {
    document.querySelector(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.querySelector(y).classList.remove("error-red");
  }

  function showER() {
    document.querySelector(Dom.errorCase).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementsByClassName(Dom.errorDes)[0].innerHTML = "the \" From time \" is already chosen";
    document.querySelector(Dom.inputTimeF).classList.add("error-red");
  }

  var exit;

  return {
      refuseDuplicatedPlans: function(from, to) {
        var exit;
        if (fromT.indexOf(from) === -1) {
          fromT.push(from);
          exit = false;
        } else {
          console.log('value already exist');
          showER();
          exit = true;
        }
    }
  };
})(UIController);


  var controller = (function(interCtrl, UICtrl) {
    var input, newPlan, DOM;

    DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

      function setupEventListeners() {
        document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", ctrlAddPlans);

        document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.activeElement.blur();
            ctrlAddPlans();
          }
        });
      }

      function removeFocus() {
        console.log('remove Focus got trigered');

        document.querySelector(DOM.inputTimeF, DOM.inputTimeT, DOM.inputText).addEventListener("focus", function() {
          // document.activeElement.blur();
          console.log("hello world");
        });
      }

      var ctrlAddPlans = function() {
        //3.get the filed input data
        input = UICtrl.getInput();
        console.log(input);
        // 4.Refuse duplicated plans
        interCtrl.refuseDuplicatedPlans(input.inputTimeF, input.inputTimeT);
        //5.add the plan to the internalController
        newPlan = interCtrl.addItem(input.inputDay, input.inputTimeF, input.inputTimeT, input.inputText, input.goingToCkecked);
        //6.add the plan to the UI
        UICtrl.addPlanList(newPlan, input.inputDay);
        //7.clear the fields;
        interCtrl.clearFields(UICtrl.getDOMstrings().inputTimeF, UICtrl.getDOMstrings().inputTimeT, UICtrl.getDOMstrings().inputText);
      };

      return {
        init: function() {
          console.log('the app has started');
          setupEventListeners();
        },
      };
    })(internalController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

I want the short circuit to be in the controller module after the `refuseDuplicatedPlans(`) method of course if it returns true I want the module to stop it's execution and thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: as a side note, you would greatly benefit by optimizing your syntax. Variables are not declared at the top and you can better use functions to handle small tasks here via the use of closures, rather than making them tightly coupled to the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

Your refuseDuplicatedPlans() method do not return anything right now. Please add a return statement to it as

```
refuseDuplicatedPlans: function(from, to) {

        var exit;
              if (fromT.indexOf(from) === -1) {
                fromT.push(from);
                exit=false;
              } else {
                console.log('value already exist');
                showER();
                exit=true;
              }
        return exit;
            }
```

After that you can put your if else call and stop execution if true.

```
if(interCtrl.refuseDuplicatedPlans(input.inputTimeF, input.inputTimeT)){
   reutrn;
}
```